# Error in interaction with web elements using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have `Python-3.4.1 32 bit` on a `Windows 7 64 bit` machine with `Selenium` using `Google Chrome version 39`. I am endeavoring to automatically download a `CSV` file from a secured website after logging in. In Chrome, while opening this website, it gives an icon saying `Load unsafe script` which we have to manually click to load the different elements on the website. I have to click on a `Menu` button which opens a drop down list from which I have to click a button. The code for the portion of page is:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html id="ext-gen3" class=" ext-strict x-viewport" decorator="blank">
        <head></head>
        <body id="ext-gen4" class="ext-gecko3 ext-linux cwc-view x-border-layout-ct" onload="cwc.getFrameworkWindow()">
            <div id="cwc_header" class=" masthead x-border-panel" style="left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1366px; height: 27px;"></div>
            <div id="cwcNavPanel" class=" x-panel cwc-navPanel x-border-panel" style="width: 220px; left: 0px; top: 56px;"></div>
            <div id="cwcCenterPanel" class=" x-tab-panel cwc-centerPanel x-border-panel" style="left: 228px; top: 35px; width: 1138px;">
                <a id="mainContent"></a>
                <div id="ext-gen55" class="x-tab-panel-header x-unselectable x-tab-panel-header-plain" style="width: 1138px;"></div>
                <div id="ext-gen56" class="x-tab-panel-bwrap">
                    <div id="ext-gen57" class="x-tab-panel-body x-tab-panel-body-top" style="width: 1138px; height: 331px;">
                        <div id="ext-comp-943917" class=" x-panel x-panel-noborder x-hide-nosize" style="width: 1136px;"></div>
                        <div id="ext-comp-943936" class=" x-panel x-panel-noborder" style="width: 1136px;">
                            <div id="ext-gen365" class="x-panel-bwrap">
                                <div id="ext-gen366" class="x-panel-body x-panel-body-noheader x-panel-body-noborder" style="width: 1136px; height: 330px;">
                                    <div id="mif-comp-943937" class=" x-panel x-panel-noborder" style="width: 1136px;">
                                        <div id="ext-gen368" class="x-panel-bwrap">
                                            <div id="ext-gen369" class="x-panel-tbar x-panel-tbar-noheader x-panel-tbar-noborder" style="width: 1136px;">
                                                <div id="ext-comp-943935" class="x-toolbar x-small-editor x-toolbar-layout-ct" style="width: 1136px;">
                                                    <table class="x-toolbar-ct" cellspacing="0">
                                                        <tbody>
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td class="x-toolbar-left" align="left">
                                                                    <table cellspacing="0">
                                                                        <tbody>
                                                                            <tr class="x-toolbar-left-row">
                                                                                <td id="ext-gen422" class="x-toolbar-cell"></td>
                                                                                <td id="ext-gen424" class="x-toolbar-cell"></td>
                                                                                <td id="ext-gen426" class="x-toolbar-cell"></td>
                                                                                <td id="ext-gen428" class="x-toolbar-cell"></td>
                                                                                <td id="ext-gen430" class="x-toolbar-cell"></td>
                                                                                <td id="ext-gen432" class="x-toolbar-cell"></td>
                                                                                <td id="ext-gen434" class="x-toolbar-cell">
                                                                                    <table id="ext-comp-943967" class="x-btn ltr x-btn-noicon x-btn-menu-active" cellspacing="0" style="width: auto;">
                                                                                        <tbody class="x-btn-small x-btn-icon-small-left">
                                                                                            <tr></tr>
                                                                                            <tr>
                                                                                                <td class="x-btn-ml"></td>
                                                                                                <td class="x-btn-mc ">
                                                                                                    <em id="ext-gen436" class="x-btn-arrow" unselectable="on" role="menu" aria-haspopup="true">
                                                                                                        <button id="ext-gen435" class=" x-btn-text" type="button">

                                                                                                            More

                                                                                                        </button>
                                                                                                    </em>
                                                                                                </td>
                                                                                                <td class="x-btn-mr"></td>
                                                                                            </tr>
                                                                                            <tr></tr>
                                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                                    </table>
                                                                                </td>
                                                                            </tr>
                                                                        </tbody>
                                                                    </table>
                                                                </td>
                                                                <td class="x-toolbar-right" align="right"></td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>
                                                    </table>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <div id="ext-gen370" class="x-panel-body ux-mif-mask-target x-panel-body-noheader x-panel-body-noborder" style="width: 1136px; height: 303px;"></div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--

             Telephony Applet 

            -->
            <iframe id="ext-gen358" class="ext-shim" frameborder="0" src="/sm/js/9.33.4005/extjs/resources/images/default/s.gif" style="display: block; visibility: visible; z-index: 14998; left: 617px; top: 84px; width: 170px; height: 246px;"></iframe>
            <div id="ext-comp-943902" class="x-tip" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20002; visibility: hidden; width: 76px; left: 666px; top: 86px; display: none;"></div>
            <div id="cwcNavPanel-xsplit" class="x-layout-split x-layout-split-west x-unselectable x-splitbar-h" style="left: 220px; top: 56px; height: 332px;"></div>
            <div id="ext-gen54" class=" x-unselectable x-splitbar-proxy x-splitbar-proxy-h"></div>
            <div id="ext-gen359" style="position: absolute; left: -1000px; top: -1000px; visibility:…; text-transform: none; letter-spacing: normal; width: auto;"></div>
            <div id="ext-gen76" class="x-shadow" style="z-index: 14999; left: 617px; top: 84px; width: 170px; height: 246px; display: block;"></div>
            <div id="ext-comp-943968" class="x-menu x-menu-floating x-layer" style="position: absolute; z-index: 15000; visibility: visible; left: 621px; top: 81px;" role="application">
                <a id="ext-gen445" class="x-menu-focus" tabindex="-1" onclick="return false;" href="#" role="presentation" aria-labelledby="ext-comp-943968"></a>
                <ul id="ext-gen446" class="x-menu-list" style="height: 244px;" role="menu">
                    <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-943969" class="x-menu-list-item" role="presentation"></li>
                    <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-943970" class="x-menu-list-item" role="presentation"></li>
                    <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-943971" class="x-menu-list-item" role="presentation"></li>
                    <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-943972" class="x-menu-list-item" role="presentation"></li>
                    <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-943973" class="x-menu-list-item" role="presentation"></li>
                    <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-943974" class="x-menu-list-item" role="presentation"></li>
                    <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-943975" class="x-menu-list-item" role="presentation"></li>
                    <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-943976" class="x-menu-list-item" role="presentation"></li>
                    <li id="x-menu-el-ext-comp-943977" class="x-menu-list-item x-menu-item-active" role="presentation">
                        <a id="ext-comp-943977" class="x-menu-item x-unselectable" href="#" unselectable="on" hidefocus="true" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">
                            <img id="ext-gen464" class="x-menu-item-icon " src="/sm/js/9.33.4005/extjs/resources/images/default/s.gif" alt=""></img>
                            <span id="ext-gen465" class="x-menu-item-text">

                                Export to Excel

                            </span>
                        </a>
```

I need to manipulate `More` (`button id="ext-gen435"` in the code above) and `Export to Excel` (`span id="ext-gen465"` in the code above) elements and to manipulate `More` button I tried:

```
d_menu = driver.find_element_by_id("ext-gen389")
```

But the id (`"ext-gen389"`) keeps changing so I tried:

```
d_menu = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Menu"]')
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(d_menu).click(d_menu).perform()
```

But that is giving me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\arjun_m\Desktop\Head_Bashing\Running_Chrome_HPSM.py", line 72, in <module>
    d_menu = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Menu"]')
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.65)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301325 (962dea43ddd90e7e4224a03fa3c36a421281abb7),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

How do I deal with those two elements?

I tried:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"Menu")]').click()
```

and it gave me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"Menu")]').click()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element
  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.65)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301325 (962dea43ddd90e7e4224a03fa3c36a421281abb7),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

I tried:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"Menu")]').click()
```

and it's giving me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#33>", line 1, in <module>
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"Menu")]').click()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 662, in find_element
    {'using': by, 'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 173, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 166, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Runtime.evaluate threw exception: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null
  (Session info: chrome=39.0.2171.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.12.301325 (962dea43ddd90e7e4224a03fa3c36a421281abb7),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1 x86_64)
```

What does it mean by **TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null** in the trace shown above?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with different selector? Like with `cssSelector`?

Comment: No I haven't. Can you please elucidate?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be that it's trying to perform an exact match, but the text you're matching is not an exact match.

Try this:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"Menu")]').click()
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//span[contains(text(),"Export to Excel")]').click()
```

Comment: I assume that is the case. Not exact match

Comment: @Richard, I tried your codes and it gave me an error. I have included them in my post. Please advise!

Comment: @Arun - `NoSuchElement` exception can be caused by two things, typically.  Either the element is in an `iframe` (I don't think this is the case) or it is slow to load.

Comment: @Richard I am using `time.sleep(x)` where x is the sufficient amount of time for the page to load before I am trying to execute the codes. How do I manipulate **iframe** elements. I don't have much notion about it. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: @Richard : I tried your `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[contains(text(),"Menu")]').click()` and it's giving me new exceptions. I have added it above. Can you suggest something? **Thanks**